# import.io Magic extractor: how to use regionText?

Tags: import.io

The [API doc](http://api.docs.import.io/#!/Magic_Methods/magic) and [support article](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/449850-magic) are a bit unclear about the exact usage of the regionText parameter.

Is it supposed to be a simple string or an XPath? For example, look at http://www.circlecount.com/community/114481059214254340537 - I would like to extract the table in the middle-right. My current API request looks like this:

https://api.import.io/store/data/_magic?url=http://www.circlecount.com/community/114481059214254340537&regionText=//*[@id=follower_table_114481059214254340537]&_apikey=XXX&_user=YYY

Answer (score 0):

Region text should be simple string, not an xpath